# Getting Data Back after Wrong Data Restore in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, restore, disaster-recovery

I would like to inquire if there is an possible way to return lost data that stored in a Sql server Database after making a wrong database restore?

I know it is extremely hard to get a positive solution but any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: As always said, before doing something like above or critical on ur DB's, you should always have the DB backed up. So if you have the latest FUll, and log backups of that DB with you, restoring would help here

Comment: Do you have previous backups of the transaction log? How many days of full backups did you have prior to the restore?

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that I have no backup files for the DB !!

Comment: This is an expensive lesson to learn, but now that you've learned it, hopefully that is useful for next time... don't do anything to SQL Server without first securing valid, tested backups.

Comment: any chance of a san-based snapshot somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The database has log and data files that are stored on the file system. If the sys admin has a process of regularly backing up the location where the database files are stored then you might be able to get some of the data back. Assuming that you can get these files from before you overwrote them - then create a new database and attach the db and log file to it. You will most likely still have some problems but you might get some data back.

Answer (score 0):

No backup, its almost a zero chance of recovering the original data:

Only thing can help if you have anyone of these like snaphsot, ,mirroring, LOGshipping or replication enabled for that database.

Have not heard, a roll back without proper backups!

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to inquire if there is an possible way to return lost data that stored in a Sql server Database after making a wrong database restore?

No. There is NO way to get the data back. You might have used **[`RESTORE .. with REPLACE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191315%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)** which **REPLACES** the data in the database with the data from the backup that you just restored. So there is no way.

You should have backup of the database that you just overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Look to see if the data is stored somewhere else.

Perhaps the system sends email confirmations. If so, retrieve the emails (from sent items or from auditing on the email system) and hire some temps to retype the information.

Perhaps the system prints out reports. If so, obtain the printouts and get the temps typing.

Perhaps the system exports data and sends it somewhere else. If so, get the exported data back from where it went and get those temps typing.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your only option is a super long shot hail mary.  WITH REPLACE replaces the old DB but I'm not sure if it explicitly searches for those DB pages on disk and tries to overwrite the pages even if the DB is different.  If the data is only 'marked' for deletion from the OS then you can have a very expensive data recovery center look at it.  Sometimes, and I mean with a lot of money, they can look at the magnetic residue and rebuild something from there but the odds of coming out of there without any issues are probably slim.

I do have to say though, I did have a client recover a QBooks database that way once, and I was really surprised that we got the data back.